# After adding new field the output is coming NaN in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

> Blockquote
>   After selecting the category,the input field is length,width,thikenes.based on this input i am  getting this output:-
>    Screed qty:1050,Cement:189bags,sand:12.60cft
>   But the problem is after clicking the + button its showing NaN, i need to store previous output value mast be added to new output insted on NaN value.

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function($scope) {

     /* Start constants declaration*/
    $scope.type={"M20 (1:1.5:3)":{cement:"0.180",sand :"0.012",mmaggregate20:"0.017",mmaggregate12:"0.007"},
                 "M21 (1:1.5:3)":{cement:"0.227",sand :"0.012",mmaggregate20:"0.017",mmaggregate12:"0.007"}};
                        
     /*End constants declaration*/

     /*Start user input values and Function to add/remove input fields*/
     $scope.choices = [{id : 'choice1', l2 : 10, b2 : 10,d2:10}];
     $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
          var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
          $scope.choices.push({'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo});
     };

     $scope.removeChoice = function() {
          var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
          $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
     };

     $scope.sum = function() {
          var sum = 0;
          angular.forEach($scope.choices, function(choice) {
               sum += choice.l2 * choice.b2*choice.d2;
          });
          return sum;
     }
     /*End user input values and Function to add/remove input fields*/


     /*End function to select units*/

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
     <body>
          <div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
                <script src="scc.js"></script>
               <!--Start Input calculation-->
               Select a category:
               <select ng-model="selectedgrade" ng-options="x for (x, y) in type" >
               </select>
          
               <br> <b>Input</b>
               <form  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
                    {{$index + 1}} :
                    Length:<input type="number" ng-model="choice.l2"  />
                    width: <input type="number" ng-model="choice.b2"  />
                    Thickness: <input id="area" type="number" ng-model="choice.d2"  />
                    <button  ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button>

                    <button  ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
                    </br>
               </form>
               <h2>cement: {{selectedgrade.cement}}</h2>
               <!--End Input  calculation-->
               <br> <b>Output</b><br>
               
               Screed qty:{{(sum() + (sum() * 0.05))}}<br>
               Cement:{{((sum() + (sum() * 0.05))*selectedgrade.cement)|number:0}}bags<br>
               sand:{{((sum() + (sum() * 0.05))*selectedgrade.sand)|number:2}}cft<br>
               
               <!--end Output calculation-->
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you adding new blank item, you should specify properties l2, b2, d2 to zero or change sum function code to something like this (because number with undefined go to NaN):

```
$scope.sum = function() {
          var sum = 0;
          angular.forEach($scope.choices, function(choice) {
               if(choice && choice.l2 && choice.b2 && choice.d2)
                   sum += choice.l2 * choice.b2*choice.d2;
          });
          return sum;
     }
```

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function($scope) {

     /* Start constants declaration*/
    $scope.type={"M20 (1:1.5:3)":{cement:"0.180",sand :"0.012",mmaggregate20:"0.017",mmaggregate12:"0.007"},
                 "M21 (1:1.5:3)":{cement:"0.227",sand :"0.012",mmaggregate20:"0.017",mmaggregate12:"0.007"}};
                        
     /*End constants declaration*/

     /*Start user input values and Function to add/remove input fields*/
     $scope.choices = [{id : 'choice1', l2 : 10, b2 : 10,d2:10}];
     $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
          var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
          $scope.choices.push({'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo, l2:0, b2:0,d2:0});
     };

     $scope.removeChoice = function() {
          var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
          $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
     };

     $scope.sum = function() {
          var sum = 0;
          angular.forEach($scope.choices, function(choice) {
            if(choice && choice.l2 && choice.b2 && choice.d2)
               sum += choice.l2 * choice.b2*choice.d2;
          });
          return sum;
     }
     /*End user input values and Function to add/remove input fields*/


     /*End function to select units*/

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
     <body>
          <div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
                <script src="scc.js"></script>
               <!--Start Input calculation-->
               Select a category:
               <select ng-model="selectedgrade" ng-options="x for (x, y) in type" >
               </select>
          
               <br> <b>Input</b>
               <form  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
                    {{$index + 1}} :
                    Length:<input type="number" ng-model="choice.l2"  />
                    width: <input type="number" ng-model="choice.b2"  />
                    Thickness: <input id="area" type="number" ng-model="choice.d2"  />
                    <button  ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button>

                    <button  ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
                    </br>
               </form>
               <h2>cement: {{selectedgrade.cement}}</h2>
               <!--End Input  calculation-->
               <br> <b>Output</b><br>
               
               Screed qty:{{(sum() + (sum() * 0.05))}}<br>
               Cement:{{((sum() + (sum() * 0.05))*selectedgrade.cement)|number:0}}bags<br>
               sand:{{((sum() + (sum() * 0.05))*selectedgrade.sand)|number:2}}cft<br>
               
               <!--end Output calculation-->
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```